# Valid Parenthesis Empty Stack Exception

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the problem statement at [Valid Parenthesis](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/description/)

I have been editing and modifying for a while and needed help. Thank you all for the initial help on the syntax issue.

The error I'm getting is for the input case of s ="()" my code returns the Empty Stack Exception instead of just "True"

```
java.util.EmptyStackException
  at line 101, java.base/java.util.Stack.peek
  at line 83, java.base/java.util.Stack.pop
  at line 37, Solution.isValid
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!!!

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    Stack stack1 = new Stack();

    public boolean isValid(String s) {

    int stringSize= s.length();

    boolean g = true;

for (int x=0; x <stringSize; x++)
{
    switch (s.charAt(x)){

    case '(':
    stack1.push(x);
    break;

    case '{':
    stack1.push(x);
    break;

    case '[':
    stack1.push(x);
    break;

    case ')':{
    if(stack1.empty()){
        g=false;
        return false;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="("){
        break;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="{"){
        g=false;
        return false;
     }
        
    else if (stack1.pop()=="["){
        g=false;
        return false;
       }
    }


     case '}':{
    if(stack1.empty()){
        g=false;
        return false;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="{"){
        break;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="("){
        g=false;
        return false;
       }
        
    else if (stack1.pop()=="["){
        g=false;
        return false;
       }
    }

    case ']':{
    if(stack1.empty()){
         g=false;
        return false;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="["){
        break;}

    else if (stack1.pop()=="("){
        g=false;
        return false;
        }
        
    else if (stack1.pop()=="{"){
        g=false;
        return false;
        }
    }

}
}

    return g;
}

    }
```

Comment: can you share some output // inputs?

Comment: your switch switch (x) and x is int from the for loop and you compare it with '(' chachter but x hold only int value from 0 till the length of the string

Comment: i guess yo ment s.charAt(x)

Comment: Thank you! I am now getting an Empty Stack Exception for the s = "(): input case:

java.util.EmptyStackException
  at line 101, java.base/java.util.Stack.peek
  at line 83, java.base/java.util.Stack.pop
  at line 37, Solution.isValid
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main

Comment: you welcome could you update your code and also what is the input and the exception you get for that input

Comment: another issue that stack1.pop()=="(" stack is full of integer as you push x `stack1.push(x);` not the chat at x same as s.charat(x) also you will get another one stack after this update will be full of char which you can not compare to string "(" so  use '(' single qoute instead of the double qoute "("

Comment: to make the compiler help you that it better to use paramter type of the stack like Stack<Character> stack1 = new Stack<>();

Comment: better way to use [arraydeque] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html instead of stack

Comment: here some tutorial about the collection framework in java https://dev.java/learn/api/collections-framework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `s.charAt(x)` instead of `x` in various places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978408/valid-parenthesis-boolean-issue#comment134004958_75978408): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)